# How to say "some sort of reason"

Tags: meaning, grammar

Is it common to say *There is some sort of reason to support my stance on this*? How do we say *some sort of reason* in such sentences?

Comment: There is some evidence to support my stance on this.

Answer (score 5):

*Some sort of* is generally used to when the speaker doesn't know the exact nature of whatever is being referred to. For example:

- He was in some sort of trouble.

implies that we don't know exactly what sort of trouble he was in.

Therefore your sentence:

- There is some sort of reason to support my stance on this.

implies that you are not entirely sure of the reason(s).

If this is not the case then write simply:

- There is some reason to support my stance on this.

or

- There are some reasons to support my stance on this.

Both of these remove the implication that you are uncertain what these reasons may be.

Comment: I agree with Shoe.  If you wanted to retain the uncertainty, you could say, "There is some vague reason I feel this way."  _Some sort of_ is rather informal – nothing wrong with dropping it in conversation, but there are probably better ways to express it, particularly in writing.

Answer (score 1):

As Shoe notes, "some sort of" indicates uncertainty. It seems unlikely in this context, like you're saying, "I have reasons, but I don't know what they are." (Well, I guess a lot of people engage in muddled thinking like that.)

What exactly are you trying to say? If you simply want to say that you have reasons, then leave out the "some sort of", as in, "I have reasons for my stand on this." You might want to give some indication of what those reasons are, like "The scientific evidence backs up my stand on this" or "The accounting department agrees that my stand on this will make them more efficient" or whatever the context is.

Comment: +1 particularly for the bracketed "aside". It's not easy to see what someone means by claiming they have reasons (of their own), but don't know what they are.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's common enough for people to say, "I have reasons but I'm too busy to tell you what they are" or "but I can't explain because you wouldn't understand" or "you must take my word for it because I am an Expert" or the like. Well there may be times when I really wouldn't understand, etc, in general when I hear such an argument, I conclude that the speaker has no good evidence, or he would be happy to present it. How much weaker still if the speaker admits he's not sure of his reasons himself!